# YouTube Data API Quota Exceeded Error Despite Low Usage According to Google Cloud Console

Tags: youtube-data-api

Why am I receiving a "quota exceeded" error when using the YouTube Data API, even though my quota usage is well below the limit according to the Google Cloud Console API and IAM Admin quotas pages?

After the above, I even created a new Google account and API key for testing purposes (ie. no usage history), but I still receive the same error. Is the API currently down / still active?

Comment: YouTube Data API v3 is still active. Provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for helping us to help you.

Comment: Create a new Google Account, Enable the YouTube Data API v3, Create a new API key, on that same page click on 'Try in API Explorer', test the API with any of their own examples in the 'Try this method' right-side panel, get a '403 exceed your quota' error.

Comment: I created a new Google Account purely because I was receiving the 'quota exceeded' error when all dashboards and metrics are telling me the opposite, and I wanted to see if perhaps the API was faulty - not to circumvent quota limits.